# Implementing Backend IP Messaging Twilio

Tags: python, ip, twilio, messaging, backend

So I'm kind of stuck. I'm trying to implement Twilio ip messaging for our app and I'm not sure I'm finding what I need in the docs.

From what I see as examples - the only things that the backend is responsible for is the credential generation - something I have done.

Should the backend also not somehow facilitate the message sending and conversation generation?

Any useful information/documentation links/tutorial links would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The message sending and conversation generation can all be done through the client libraries, either the [JavaScript](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-js) or [iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-ios) (or, coming soon, Android) SDKs. That way, other than the credential generation as you pointed out, your servers don't need to be responsible for the rest of the chat application.

You can, if you choose, send messages from your own server too. Check out the [documentation on the IP Messaging REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest).

If you want your server to interact with messages sent by the client libraries you can also subscribe to [webhooks for IP Messaging too](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/webhooks).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the information. I'll just store the messages in the local database, generate and save user credentials and let the client-side handle the rest.

Also you mentioned the Android SDK for IP Messaging is not out yet?

Comment: Oops, I misread the docs myself. Android is available here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/changelogs/android. Note, you don't need to store messages at all, they are all kept for you in the IP Messaging API.

Comment: Does Twilio deal with storing all the messages and data?

Comment: @EvanErickson it does, the chat service ([now conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/migrating-chat-conversations)) stores all the data that is sent through it and you can access it via the SDKs or the REST API.